# Chevron of CTabFolder is not scrollable

Tags: java, swt

My list in the `CTabFolder` chevron is too large. It goes from the top of my browser to the end and doesn't show all items. There is not scroll function or anything similar available (as far as I know).

How can I handle very long item lists in my chevron of the `CTabFolder`?

Comment: Could you share your code with us? Or at least provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [ScrolledComposite](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FScrolledComposite.html):

```
ScrolledComposite scrolledComp = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
Composite compForContent = new Composite(scrolledComp, SWT.NONE);
scrolledComp.setContent(compForContent);

// create your list in compForContent, don't forget about layout for compForContent

tabFolder.setControl(scrolledComp);
```